# Spring Batch In-memory (MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean) clear old jobs not the running Job

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using spring-batch to schedule the Batch Job ie In-memory as project specific requirement (ie not in Production its Just for Test Environment), below are my configuration classes which looks like

```
// Batch Scheulder class
    package org.learning.scheduler
    import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

    /**
     * Job Inmemory Config
     * 
     */
    @EnableScheduling
    @Configuration
    public class InmemoryJobConfig  {


        @Bean
        public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
        }

        @Bean
        public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager) throws Exception {
            MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(resourcelessTransactionManager);
            factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factoryBean;
        }

        @Bean
        public JobRepository jobRepository(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean) throws Exception{
            return (JobRepository) factoryBean.getObject();
        }
        @Bean
        public JobExplorer jobExplorer(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean repositoryFactory) {
            return new SimpleJobExplorer(repositoryFactory.getJobInstanceDao(), repositoryFactory.getJobExecutionDao(),
                    repositoryFactory.getStepExecutionDao(), repositoryFactory.getExecutionContextDao());
        }

        @Bean
        public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
            SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
            simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
            simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());

            return simpleJobLauncher;
        }
    }

//Job ConfiguratinClass

/**
 * Batch Entry Point for Scheduler for all Jobs
 *
 * 
 */
@Import({InmemoryJobConfig.class})
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class BatchScheduler {


    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Autowired
    private SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher;


    @Autowired
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    @Autowired
    private MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean;


    @Bean
    public ItemReader<UserDTO> userReader() {
        return new UserReader();

    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<User> userWriter() {
        return new UserWriter();

    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<OrderDTO> orderReader() {
        return new OrderReader();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Order> orderWriter() {
        return new OrderWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step userStep(ItemReader<UserDTO> reader, ItemWriter<User> writer) {
        return steps.get("userStep")
                .<UserDTO, User>chunk(20)
                .reader(userReader())
                .processor(new UserProcessor())
                .writer(userWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step orderStep(ItemReader<OrderDTO> reader, ItemWriter<Order> writer) {
        return steps.get("orderStep")
                .<OrderDTO, Order>chunk(20)
                .reader(orderReader())
                .processor(new OrderProcessor())
                .writer(orderWriter())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Job userJob() {
        return jobs.get("userJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(userStep(userReader(), userWriter())).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job orderJob() {
        return jobs.get("orderJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(orderStep(orderReader(), orderWriter())).build();
    }


    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * * *  ?")
    public void scheduleUserJob() throws JobExecutionException {
        Set<JobExecution> runningJob = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions("userJob");

        if (!runningJob.isEmpty()) {
            throw new JobExecutionException(" User Job  is already in Start State  ");
        }

        JobParameters userParam =
                new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("date", System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(userJob(), userParam);

    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * * *  ?")
    public void scheduleOrderJob() throws JobExecutionException {
        Set<JobExecution> runningJob = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions("orderJob");

        if (!runningJob.isEmpty()) {
            throw new JobExecutionException(" Order Job  is already in Start State  ");
        }

        JobParameters orderParam =
                new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("date", System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(orderJob(), orderParam);

    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/30 * * *  ?")
    public void scheduleCleanupMemoryJob() throws BatchException {
        Set<JobExecution> orderRunningJob = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions("orderJob");
        Set<JobExecution> userRunningJob = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions("userJob");
        if (!orderRunningJob.isEmpty() || !userRunningJob.isEmpty()) {
            throw new BatchException(" Order/user Job  is running state , cleanup job is aborted  ");
        }

        mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.clear();

    }
}
```

I have two Job scheduled on every 0/15 minutes which will do some business logic and i have scheduled in-memory cleanup job to clean the in-memory job data from the "mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" bean only if any of these two Job is not running state .

I want suggestion to find the best approach how to delete the old Jobs which is already executed , the above approach will not delete the old Job details if its any of the Job is in running state.

Or is there any API's from spring-batch to clear the specific job details from in-memory once the Job is executed .? ie clear in-memory by JobId

**Note** : I want to go with **MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean** only not persistent database or any embedded database(H2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MapJobRepository` provides a [`clear()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html#clear--) method that clears all data in the map based job repository but I don't see any obvious way to remove the meta-data of a specific job.

> I want to go with MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean only not persistent database or any embedded database(H2)

I really recommend using the JDBC based job repository with an in-memory DB instead. This approach is better because it allows you to run queries against your in-memory db and remove data for a specific job.